# html5 canvas transform shadow

Tags: html, canvas

Is it possible to apply transformation to the shadow?
For example, to the shadow of the rectangle was diamond shaped.

```
<div><canvas id="myCanvas" width="900" height = "700" style="border:solid 1px #000000;"></canvas></div>

<script>
    var context = document.getElementById("myCanvas").getContext("2d");

    function draw_rectangle() {
        context.shadowOffsetX = 50;
        context.shadowOffsetY = 50;
        context.shadowBlur = 5;
        context.shadowColor = "DarkGoldenRod";
        context.strokeStyle = "Gold";
        context.strokeRect(200, 200, 100, 120);
    }
    window.onload = draw_rectangle();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use css3 for this?
Here you might find how to do so : http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-shadow.asp

Comment: I know about CSS capabilities for this. Need to transform a shadow using canvas API, without CSS.

Answer (score 0):

No, You can’t transform the shadow separately from the rectangle.

You *can* rotate both the rectangle+shadow like this:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/W4fgp/

You could also draw the 2 objects separately,  1 rectangle and 1 rectangle for the “shadow”.

Here is code rotating your rectangle+shadow:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
    $(function(){

        var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
        var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

        ctx.rotate(.6);
        ctx.rect(150, 50, 50, 60);
        ctx.shadowOffsetX = 50;
        ctx.shadowOffsetY = 50;
        ctx.shadowBlur = 5;
        ctx.shadowColor = "DarkGoldenRod";
        ctx.strokeStyle = "Gold";
        ctx.stroke();

    }); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I need "falling" shadow which does not repeat the form of it's source, like rectangle -> diamond, circle -> ellipse and so on. Drawing two separate objects will do the trick, but it is not what I need exactly.

Comment: To show the 2nd shadow-object "falling", you should check out the Skew transform. This article is for photoshop but it fits your situation because the information is really about skewing a copy of an image to create a perspective shadow effect...http://www.adobetutorialz.com/articles/218/1/Perspective-Shadow